# Override vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Http/Controllers/ContentTypes/Image.php Voyager/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

How could you overrider the functionality of vendor/tcg/voyager/src/Http/Controllers/ContentTypes/Image.php without editing the voyager file?

I have been trying to change the internal functions of Image.php without success, any idea how to do it without modifying voyager?

Comment: This may be a good place to start https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php